# Puppeteer getting Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText') when returning multiple values

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Using puppeteer to get some data from a site. I need to return multiple values gotten from the site but for some reason I can only return one at a time, anytime I try returning multiple values(like the one in the code below), I get the following error: `Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText') when returning multiple values` and I can't find out why.

**Code**

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const chromeBrowser = await puppeterr.launch({ headless: true });
        const page = await chromeBrowser.newPage();
        await page.goto("https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/category=form-cat2", {timeout: 0});

    const getInfo = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const secTableEN = document.querySelector(".table td.entity-name");
        const secTableFiled = document.querySelector(".table td.entity-filed");
        const secTableLink = document.querySelector(".table td.filetype");

        return {
            secTableEN: secTableEN.innerText,
            secTableFiled: secTableFiled.innerText,
        };
    })

    console.log(getInfo);
    await page.close();
    await chromeBrowser.close();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})();
```

Comment: Looks like a selector issue.  You are getting a `null` value from either or both of the queries.  Check your `querySelector`s in the dev tools of the page you are scraping.

Comment: The selectors seem fine to me, if I try returning only one i.e `return secTableEN.innerText` only or `return secTableFiled.innerText` it works perfectly, but any attempt at returning more than one value results in this exact same error.

Comment: @ggorlen Yeah that fixed it. Such a simple fix and I struggled so much to see it...Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The page loads the data dynamically, so you should `waitForSelector` before querying.
2. `.entity-filed` should be `.filed`.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.0.0

const url = "<your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const $ = (...args) => page.waitForSelector(...args);
  const text = async (...args) =>
    (await $(...args)).evaluate(el => el.textContent.trim());
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const info = {
    secTableEN: await text(".table td.entity-name"),
    secTableFiled: await text(".table td.filed"),
    secTableLink: await text(".table td.filetype"),
  };
  console.log(info);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

As an aside, I wouldn't use `{timeout: 0}`. If the page doesn't load after a minute or so, something is wrong and you should probably report an error rather than hang the script forever.

---

Another approach is to avoid the DOM and simply intercept the API response with the payload you're interested in:

```js
// ... same boilerplate as above ...
browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const [page] = await browser.pages();
const resP = page.waitForResponse(res =>
  res.url() === "https://efts.sec.gov/LATEST/search-index"
);
await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
const res = await resP;
const data = JSON.parse(await res.text());
const hit = data.hits.hits[0]._source;
const info = {
  secTableEN: hit.display_names[0],
  secTableFiled: hit.file_date,
  secTableLink: hit.file_type // slightly different output than from the DOM
};
console.log(info);
// ...
```